# I want to disable browser events on focus of an element

Tags: javascript, browser, event-listener

I am trying to create a typing speed checker. I have added keyboard animations on keypress it shows whiskey has been pressed. But when I am pressing the '`space`' bar it is scrolling, or when pressing the '`tab`' it changes focus to the address bar. Which I don't want to happen when practicing typing.

Is there any javascript code that I can use to disable it?

Comment: you probably just need `event.preventDefault()` inside the event listener

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the browser that is doing the "default action" for that event, so you have to tell him not to do it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // all the thing you should do
});
```